# JS Validate fields that have been added on the fly?

Tags: jquery

I have an input field with the class questionInput, I want to validate it using js validate.

The problem is the user is allowed to add in more questions when they press a button, this clones the original field. Creating more fields with the class questionInput.

I've tried adding in:

```
$('.questionInput').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required:  "fill in this field please"
            }
        });
    });
```

But this does not seem to work.

Does anyone know how i can do this?